# Looking for an effective way to remove part of each item from the List<String>

Tags: java-8

I have list of string items and I am trying remove the part of the string in each item and create new list with it. I am able to achieve it using below code but I feel there will be a better way of handling this using stream api's. Please let me know if any better approach available for this problem

Please see below for example(simplified for explanation)

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Value1.1,Value1.2,Value1.3,Value1.4,Value1.5,Value1.6");
    list.add("Value2.1,Value2.2,Value2.3,Value2.4,Value2.5,Vaule2.6");

    List<String> newList = list.stream().map(i -> {
            List<String> l = Arrays.asList(i.split(","));
            return StringUtils.join(ListUtils.sum(l.subList(0, 2),l.subList(4, l.size())),",");
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

newList.forEach(System.out::println);
//    Value1.1,Value1.2,Value1.5,Value1.6
//    Value2.1,Value2.2,Value2.5,Value1.6
```

#### Problem Statement:

- Input is "list"(List of String)
- Iterate each item in the list and split each item by comma and drop 3rd and 4th element and rejoin the string
- Create new list with new string item

used: StringUtils, ListUtils from org.apache.commons

#### Expected Output:

Value1.1,Value1.2,Value1.5,Value1.6

Value2.1,Value2.2,Value2.5,Value2.6

Comment: what is your expected output from this?

Comment: added the expected output...

Comment: so what about `Value1.6` - you said only drop 3rd, 4th, but you've also dropped the last item?

Comment: Sry.. That was mistake..My bad.. Corrected the code example and output

Comment: You could use `l.subList(2, 4).clear()` to drop the 3rd and 4th element. You have to make it an `ArrayList` or something first though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to filter out the unwanted values:

```java
String pattern = "^([^,]*,[^,]*)(,[^,]*,[^,]*)(.*)$"
/** Explnation:
^              :start of line
(...)          :group capture
[^,]           :all characters which aren't ','
*              :zero or more times
,              :single comma
.              :any character
$              :end of line

([^,]*,[^,]*)  :first capture group ($1), two words seperated by ','
(,[^,]*,[^,]*) :second capture group ($2), the values we want to remove
(.*)           :third capture group ($3), all the rest of the string
**/

Pattern patternCompiled = Pattern.compile(pattern);
List<String> newList = list.stream()
                      .map(i -> patternCompiled.matcher(i).replaceAll("$1$3"))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: There is no difference to `.map(i -> i.replaceAll("^([^,]*,[^,]*)(,[^,]*,[^,]*)(.*)$", "$1$3")`, unless you keep and reuse the result of `Pattern.compile(pattern)`.

Answer (score 1):

try using remove,

`list.remove("Value1.1");`

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Value1.1,Value1.2,Value1.3,Value1.4,Value1.5,Value1.6");
        list.add("Value2.1,Value2.2,Value2.3,Value2.4,Value2.5,Vaule2.6");

        List<String> newList = list.stream().map(i ->
            Arrays.stream(i.split(","))
                    .filter(s -> s.endsWith("1") || s.endsWith("2") || s.endsWith("5"))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());

        newList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

I think this is a right solution because you still need to do map operation on every string in array. Then only this item need to be 'repackaged' to new string.

Comment: I wanted to remove the item based on index. I cannot do a filter with condition "string.endsWith" since the value could be anything and i have used "Valuex.x" as an example but i actually i want to  drop by index(3rd and 4th) after comma split..